# Twitter tweetinvi streaming filtering using `and`

Tags: twitter, tweetinvi

Is it possible to perform the following kind of streaming filter (pseudocode)?

```
(track = "shooter" and location = "Miami") or (track = "flood" and location="Los Angeles") or ...
```

I think it might not be possible because of the following ([quoted from the documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter.html)):

> The track, follow, and locations fields should be considered to be
>   combined with an OR operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You would need to use the enterprise PowerTrack API.

Comment: Can you provide any link showing that PowerTrack API allows for such a query?

Comment: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/premium-operators.html and https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/powertrack_rules_and_filtering should give the information you need. You can also have multiple rules per PowerTrack connection, unlike on standard.

Comment: I don't see any way to achieve the query based on those links.